# Run single test with PhpStorm and PHPUnit on Symfony project fail with error: "Cannot open file"

Tags: configuration, phpunit, phpstorm

When I run all tests with PhpStorm everything works fine but when I try to run a single test I get the error:

```
Cannot open file <namespace>.
```

We check version of PHP and PHPUnit compatibilities and everything looks fine. When I run single file test the following command is executed:

```
/php7.4.7/php.exe phpunit-9.4.2.phar --bootstrap <my_project_folder>\tests\bootstrap.php --configuration <my_project_folder>\phpunit.xml.dist --filter "/(::<ClassTestIWantToExecute)( .*)?$/" <namespace_of_classTest> <my_project_folder>\tests\EnsembleImmobilierTest.php --teamcity --cache-result-file=<my_project_folder>\.phpunit.result.cache
```

PHPUnit is executed but couldn't find the test to execute.

Comment: Are you on PhpStorm 2020.2.3?

Comment: Thank you ! I had aldready update my phpstorm but Phpstorm update one by one version. After an other update I have PhpStorm 2020.2.3 and it works fine !

Comment: That's great to hear. Good luck with your projects!